# Can a versatile weapon be wielded in your off hand?

Tags: dnd-4e, weapons

My character is a dragonborn tempest (Martial Power) fighter focused on axes. Can I fight with two battleaxes or even waraxes (Adventurers vault)? Seems a bit overpowered but if I can it will be awesome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No. A tempest fighter cannot wield normal one-handed weapons, regardless of whether they're versatile, in their off-hand.**

From PHB1, p217:

> **Off-Hand:** An off-hand weapon is light enough that you can hold it and attack effectively with it while holding a weapon in your main hand.

Thus, a *non* off-hand weapon cannot be used in your off-hand. Two-Blade *rangers* have a specific class feature that lets them bypass this restriction, but tempest fighters do *not*.

From PHB1, p104:

> **Two-Blade Fighting Style:** Because of your focus on two-weapon melee attacks, you can wield a one-handed weapon in your off hand as if it were an off-hand weapon.

In fact, tempest fighters are encouraged to use 2 *lighter* weapons by their class features. Your character will actually do as much damage with handaxes as he would with battleaxes (as long as you use light armor or chainmail), and be more accurate to boot. If you take Shock Trooper as your paragon path, those handaxes will end up being as good as waraxes.

From Martial Power 1, p7 (*emphasis mine*):

> **Tempest Technique:** When you wield two melee weapons, you gain a *+1 bonus to attack rolls with weapons that have the off-hand property*. You gain Two-Weapon Defense as a bonus feat, even if you don't meet the prerequisites. When wearing light armor or chainmail, you gain a +1 bonus to damage rolls with melee or close weapon attacks when you are wielding two weapons. *This bonus increases to +2 with weapons that have the off-hand property.*

Versatile has no effect on dual-wielding, so if your character can equip any one-handed weapon, that includes versatile weapons.

Comment: So that means ranger can equip two Waraxes (d12 each) on heroic tier? Or even on 1st level if he is a human. This just seems wrong.

Comment: It's a *class ability*.  It's one of the very distinctive things about rangers -- they've been good at dual-wielding since the early days.

Comment: @GuardNo.67: That's because a ranger is a striker, and has no purpose other than to do damage. Fighters get all kinds of other goodies to make up for it (such as marks). Also, note that you can be doing waraxe-equivalent damage with the right paragon path (see my latest edit).

Comment: For paragon path im thinking about Kensei, it will give +4 to damage per attack at 16 level what seems better than increasing the weapon’s damage die by one size (its not on  11 level but still).

Comment: Its worth noting that you can multiclass into ranger to gain the Two-Blade Fighting Style